# Why do some datasets need us to do `data(somedataset)` before we can use them?

Tags: r, dataset, lazy-loading, package

Why do we have to use `data(spam)` before we can run `lda` on it ? `spam` is a dataset in the `ElemsStatLearn` package.

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
library(MASS) # for lda
spam[5] # is ok
spam.lda = lda(spam ~ . , data = spam) # not ok
data(spam)
spam.lda = lda(spam ~ . , data = spam) # ok
```

We can access `spam[5]` even before we run `data(spam)`.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Where does `lda` and `training_data` come from ?

Comment: Apologies. I copied it from R and left training_error.

Comment: I think I was doing something wrong in another piece of script. These seem to work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R includes a range of datasets, mainly for use in examples. Some of these datasets are directly available (e.g. `iris` or `cars`), in some packages they are not automatically available requiring a call to `data` to attach them to the current workspace, e.g. `meuse` from the `gstat` package. So you experience in `ElemStatLearn` is valid, `spam` is automatically available.

Answer (score 7):

Both calls to `lda` work fine for me. `ElemStatLearn` uses [lazy loading](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#Lazy-loading) of data so you don't need to call `data`

```
> packageDescription("ElemStatLearn")[["LazyData"]]
# [1] "yes"
```